# UIWebview not scrolling in jquery part

Tags: jquery, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, highcharts

I'm making changes to an existing IPad app. I'm using highcharts (it is a jquery chart library) inside a .htm page. Im loading that htm page in uiwebview control using loadrequest method. The chart displays the data point correctly. But when the ipad is in landscape mode the chart is not getting displayed fully as some part of the chart goes down. The issue is I'm not able to scroll by swiping in the middle of the uiwebview (in the chart). But i'm able to scroll if i scroll in the corners of the webview. I want to make the webview scroll even if i scroll in the middle of the chart. Im new to IOS im not sure why webview is behaving like this. Please guide me on solving this issue.

Comment: This is because the Highchart is grabbing focus on the touch event. Let me find a link to a solution that came up recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need the user to be able to click/interact with the chart you can disable mouse tracking. See this [link](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14398). You would also need to add an overlaying div. See the last post in that thread.

Comment: disable mouse traking?? mine is a ipad native application. in that app, in webview, i display highchart that is embedded in a local html file that resides within application. The user is not able to scroll the respective webui control up & down by swiping & this happens if the user swipes on the chart area, if he swipes in the corner then the webview scroll is happening. i want the user to be able to scroll even if he touches on the chart. im not sure how disabling mousetracking will help in this issue...

Comment: If you want to let the user swipe over the chart to continue with the scrolling of the page you disable mousetracking inside of HighCharts. This means that any mouse (in your case touch) events that occur inside it are not captured. Essentially it makes the chart just another HTML object like text/image/whatever instead of an interactive item.